# Redefining some standard library parts

Tags: c++

I have a C++ library that I wrote and that relies on two other libraries, let's call them libA and libB. Both are C++14-compliant, and so is my library.

So far, so good.

Now here is the tricky part. I need to use that library in a very constrained environment: Intel SGX. I won't enter the details, straight to the problem: Intel SGX's SDK, although being C++14 compatible, makes use of a custom libstdC++. Why you ask? Because in an SGX enclave there are many system call you cannot make, especially I/O: file, console, sockets...

My issue is the following: when I add my library to the source, the compilation issues a huge load of errors, complaining that `std::cout` doesn't exist, that `FILE`is not defined, and so on. All these errors come from libA and libB's source code.

As libA and libB are quite huge, butchering their source code to get rid of everything that causes an error seems to me like a crazy idea. Resulting code woule be unmaintainable.

This morning I had an idea: what if I added to the project a header that redefines minimal versions of all that's missing? Some kind of compatibility layer that would, for example, redefine `std::cout` as a "no-operation" version.

It's the first time I encounter such an issue, and I need the elder's advice. Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Comment: Yes, I think it is doable to add stubs for the missing items, but beware that this might make libA or libB just non functional.

Comment: That's the beauty of it: as my environment doesn't allow I/O, I don't use libA/libB's I/O functions at all, so I shouldn't break anything.

Comment: The namespaces are open. You are free to add to them, if the missing items are trully not defined.

Comment: "shouldn't". But might anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a header is probably not enough. You'll probably also need some source code.

Strictly speaking this is Undefined Behavior, but so is the whole SGX. You're putting yourself in the position of the compiler writer.

It does mean you have to understand a bit more about what's expected. In particular, you need to understand how the libraries you use are packaged. If they're already compiled, and you're getting link errors, then your replacements have to be link-compatible.